# Scrapyd die after specified time deployed on server

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a spider deployed successfully on localhost and running day after day without any trouble

When deployed to my ubuntu server, process started and spider run, but after a short time, my scrapyd process stoped without give me a clue

I've increased RAM to 2gb, server : digital ocean

Has anyone run into the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: You'd have to post logs or something for us to work with. If it dies without any errors or notice you're probably running out of memory.